# re-assigning form values on a sortable jQuery UI

Tags: forms, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working on a form with text 3 sortable text fields (1,2,3) which, for the purpose of this example, will contain the text a,b,c, respectively.

I want the user to to be able to re-order/sort these fields and I want the text field name to be re-numbered.
I've created a sanbox example for you to see here: https://repl.it/repls/FeistyLinedKnowledge

Right now if you click on SUBMIT you get this:

```
   Array
(
    [q1] => a
    [q2] => b
    [q3] => c
)
```

If I drag q1 in the second position and click on SUBMIT I get this:

```
Array
(
    [q2] => b
    [q1] => a
    [q3] => c
)
```

When the result I'd like to get instead is this:

```
Array
(
    [q1] => b
    [q2] => a
    [q3] => c
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case somebody stumbles upon this post with a similar problem, I figured out that in order for this to happen I have to re-enter all values into the array by adding two square brackets "[" and "]" next to each other "[]" right next to the array name in the HTML form, like so: https://repl.it/repls/FeistyLinedKnowledge